# Tableview is nil when reloading data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I have a tableview that has two cells in it. One is a toggle switch that when disabled, changes the color of the text in the second cell to gray. I handle the switch for that cell in its custom cell class and set a boolean value for it in the table's class using `didSet` to trigger a function to reload the tableview. The problem is that the tableview I have linked to storyboard is nil when it goes to reload the data to it but only when the function is called from `didSet`. When it is called normally through some other means like in `viewDidLoad()` it works as expected. The full error is: `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`

```
    class Notifications: UIViewController {

    var notificationsEnabled:Bool = true {
        didSet {
            RefreshTable()
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var notificationsTableView: RoundedTable!

    var notificationItems = ["Notifications", "Time"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        notificationsTableView!.dataSource = self
        notificationsTableView!.delegate = self
    }

    func RefreshTable() {
        notificationsTableView.reloadData() //Crashes here
    }
}

extension Notifications: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return notificationItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {  
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "notificationToggleCell", for: indexPath) as! NotificationToggleCell
            cell.notificationToggleLbl.text = notificationItems[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        case 1:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "notificationTimeCell", for: indexPath) as! NotificationTimeCell
            cell.notificationTimeLbl.text = notificationItems[indexPath.row]
            if (!notificationsEnabled) {
                cell.notificationTimeLbl.textColor = .gray
                cell.notificationTimeTxt.textColor = .gray
            }
            return cell
        default:
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the custom cell class:

```
class NotificationToggleCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var notificationToggleLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var notificationToggleSwitch: UISwitch!

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    @IBAction func notificationSwitchChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        let notificationsViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Notifications") as! Notifications
        if (notificationToggleSwitch.isOn) {
            notificationsViewController.notificationsEnabled = true
        }
        if (!notificationToggleSwitch.isOn) {
            notificationsViewController.notificationsEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/ http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake-2/

Comment: It crashes if you call "RefreshTable" or it doesn't reload?

Comment: @A.Amini It crashes when RefreshTable() is called.

Comment: Can you write the crash log/message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use a delegate design pattern.

```
protocol NotificationsDelegate {
    func toggleSwitched()
}
```

In your NotificationToggleCell add

```
var toggleDelegate: NotificationsDelegate?

@objc func toggleSwitched() {
    toggleDelegate.toggleSwitched()
}
```

In the cellForRowAt function

```
cell. toggleDelegate = self
```

and finally

```
extension Notifications: NotificationsDelegate { 
    func toggleSwitched() {
        RefreshTable()
    }
}
```